# Non-blocking read from classpath

Tags: java, classpath, war, nio, nonblocking

Yay, Java 7, nio, and such!

I now can read a file asynchronously and be super-awesome .

But deployments are typically as JARs or WARs, so I need to read from the classpath.

How can I read from a JAR/WAR in a non-blocking manner?

Comment: Can you add your code to your post?

Comment: Question is not very clear, you want to read files using NIO ? what is use of deployment in this context ?

Comment: @Stephan, if I knew the code to add, I would know the answer.

Comment: @Ashkrit, for example, I may want to serve static assets from the WAR. But asynchronously.